# "Name does not exist in this context" error in a random item generator

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The goal is to create a random item generator, in this case potions. Everything works fine until I attempt to make the type of potion that is randomly selected actually effect the stats that they increase, which the guide i'm following didn't go over.

The errors say that the names such as HEALTH and ENERGY do not exist in this context, as well as one that says "Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'BasePotion.PotionTypes'"

I'm following a guide to create an rpg to try and learn c#. I've been following it up to this point, but decided to expand upon the code we were doing. 
I originally had the if statements in their own function, but that gave an "identifier expected" error.

```
private void CreatePotion() { 

    newPotion = new BasePotion();

    newPotion.PotionType = ChoosePotionType();
    newPotion.ItemName = newPotion.PotionType.ToString() +" POTION";
    newPotion.ItemID = Random.Range(1,100);
    if (newPotion.PotionType == HEALTH) {
        newPotion.Stamina = Random.Range(1,11);
        newPotion.Endurance = Random.Range(1,11);
        newPotion.Strength = 0;
        newPotion.Intellect = 0;
    }
    else if (newPotion.PotionType == ENERGY){
        newPotion.Stamina = 0;
        newPotion.Endurance = 0;
        newPotion.Strength = Random.Range(1,11);
        newPotion.Intellect = Random.Range(1,11);
    }
    else if (newPotion.PotionType == STAMINA){
        newPotion.Stamina = Random.Range(1,11);
        newPotion.Endurance = 0;
        newPotion.Strength = 0;
        newPotion.Intellect = 0;
    }
    else if (newPotion.PotionType == ENDURANCE){
        newPotion.Stamina = 0;
        newPotion.Endurance = Random.Range(1,11);
        newPotion.Strength = 0;
        newPotion.Intellect = 0;
    }
    else if (newPotion.PotionType == STRENGTH){
        newPotion.Stamina = 0;
        newPotion.Endurance = 0;
        newPotion.Strength = Random.Range(1,11);
        newPotion.Intellect = 0;
    }
    else if (newPotion.PotionType == INTELLECT){
        newPotion.Stamina = 0;
        newPotion.Endurance = 0;
        newPotion.Strength = 0;
        newPotion.Intellect = Random.Range(1,11);
    }
}
```

The if statements are the lines giving errors.

I don't really know how much is needed to replicate the issue, but here is the BasePotion script this derives from.

```
public enum PotionTypes {
    HEALTH,
    ENERGY,
    STRENGTH,
    ENDURANCE,
    STAMINA,
    INTELLECT
}

private PotionTypes potionType;
private int spellEffectID;

public PotionTypes PotionType {
    get { return potionType; }
    set { potionType = value; }
}

public int SpellEffectID {
    get { return spellEffectID; }
    set { spellEffectID = value; }
}
```

I have another, pretty much identical script minus the if statements to generate armor in the same way as this, and that works as expected, including assigning a Type in the same way i am in this script.

I can't really figure out what the issue is, but if anyone has a better way of going about this, that would be helpful too.

Comment: A [mcve] would be awesome. Also, when talking about errors be sure to share with us which **line of code** the **specific** error relates to.

Comment: Make sure your [mcve] includes `ChoosePotionType`'s source code.

Comment: you need to use ENERGY, HEALTH etc as PotionTypes.ENERGY, PotionTypes.HEALTH within the `if` clause. And seems like your `ChoosePotionTypes` method returns `void` so you cannot use it to assign value to `PotionType` variable. Return `PotionType` from that method.

Answer (score 1):

The first issue is that you are trying to access e.g. `HEALTH` directly from your class `BasePosition`. `HEALTH` is not a member of your class but of `PotionTypes` so you have to access it through `PotionTypes` like `PotionTypes.HEALTH`.

So add `PotionTypes.` in front of each of the enum values.

E.g. in

```
if(newPotion.PotionType == PotionTypes.HEALTH)
```

---

For the second issue we would need to know your code for `ChoosePotionType`

Apparently it is defined like

```
private void ChoosePotionType()
{ 
    ... 
}
```

but in order to use it in

```
newPotion.PotionType = ChoosePotionType();
```

it has to return a `PotionType` so it should somehow look like

```
private PotionType ChoosePotionType ()
{
    ...

    return PotionType.XY;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  That cleared up the name not existing errors, but setting it to return `PotionTypes` didn't work, but `BasePotion.PotionTypes` did. I never would have expected that was the issue, as i have 2 other scripts using that same `void ChooseItemType` function and they don't have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

As the code snippet was not adequate have created few on my own. Please find the code that works fine. When we have a multiple scenarios to consider, I prefer switch rather than if... else if

```
private static BasePotion CreatePotion()
{
    BasePotion newPotion = new BasePotion();
    newPotion.PotionType = ChoosePotionType();
    newPotion.ItemName = newPotion.PotionType.ToString() + " POTION";
    newPotion.ItemID = new Random().Next(1, 100);
    switch (newPotion.PotionType)
    {
        case PotionTypes.HEALTH:
            newPotion.Stamina = new Random().Next(1, 11);
            newPotion.Endurance = new Random().Next(1, 11);
            newPotion.Strength = 0;
            newPotion.Intellect = 0;
            break;
        case PotionTypes.ENERGY:
            newPotion.Stamina = 0;
            newPotion.Endurance = 0;
            newPotion.Strength = new Random().Next(1, 11);
            newPotion.Intellect = new Random().Next(1, 11);
            break;
        case PotionTypes.STAMINA:
            newPotion.Stamina = new Random().Next(1, 11);
            newPotion.Endurance = 0;
            newPotion.Strength = 0;
            newPotion.Intellect = 0;
            break;
        case PotionTypes.ENDURANCE:
            newPotion.Stamina = 0;
            newPotion.Endurance = new Random().Next(1, 11);
            newPotion.Strength = 0;
            newPotion.Intellect = 0;
            break;
        case PotionTypes.STRENGTH:
            newPotion.Stamina = 0;
            newPotion.Endurance = 0;
            newPotion.Strength = new Random().Next(1, 11);
            newPotion.Intellect = 0;
            break;
        case PotionTypes.INTELLECT:
            newPotion.Stamina = 0;
            newPotion.Endurance = 0;
            newPotion.Strength = 0;
            newPotion.Intellect = new Random().Next(1, 11);
            break;
    }

    return newPotion;
}

private static PotionTypes ChoosePotionType()
{
    potionType++;
    PotionTypes returnPotion;
    switch (potionType)
    {
        case 1:
            returnPotion = PotionTypes.ENERGY;
            break;
        case 2:
            returnPotion = PotionTypes.HEALTH;
            break;
        case 3:
            returnPotion = PotionTypes.ENDURANCE;
            break;
        case 4:
            returnPotion = PotionTypes.INTELLECT;
            break;
        case 5:
            returnPotion = PotionTypes.STAMINA;
            break;
        case 6:
            returnPotion = PotionTypes.STRENGTH;
            break;
        default:
            returnPotion = PotionTypes.ENERGY;
            break;
    }

    return returnPotion;
}

public enum PotionTypes
{
    HEALTH,
    ENERGY,
    STRENGTH,
    ENDURANCE,
    STAMINA,
    INTELLECT
}

public class BasePotion
{
    private PotionTypes potionType;
    private int spellEffectID;

    public int Intellect { get; internal set; }
    public int ItemID { get; internal set; }
    public string ItemName { get; internal set; }

    public PotionTypes PotionType
    {
        get { return potionType; }
        set { potionType = value; }
    }

    public int SpellEffectID
    {
        get { return spellEffectID; }
        set { spellEffectID = value; }
    }

    public int Strength { get; internal set; }
    public int Stamina { get; internal set; }

    public int Endurance { get; internal set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"ItemID:{ItemID}, ItemName:{ItemName}, PortionType:{PotionType.ToString()}, SpellEffect:{SpellEffectID}, Strength:{Strength}, Stamina:{Stamina}, Endurance: {Endurance}, Intellect: {Intellect}.";
    }
}
```

**Console Application Code**

```
private static int potionType = 0;
private static List<BasePotion> potions;
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    Console.WriteLine("Started.....");
    potions = new List<BasePotion>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        var newPortion = CreatePotion();
        potions.Add(newPortion);
        Console.WriteLine(newPortion.ToString());
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Completed.....");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```